# Get the user control while closing the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have an user control  in a windows form(Parent Form). On close of parent form I need to get the grid present in an `UserControl`. There is no close button for usercontrol. On close of Form the usercontrol is getting disposed and i can  no longer get the datagridview.

Is there any way to get the usercontrol before getting disposed in `form_closing` event? or any event in usercontrol fires while the parent form is getting closed?

Tried this one..But no use

```
void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.ParentForm.FormClosing += new  FormClosingEventHandler(ParentForm_FormClosing);
}
```

Comment: Form [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs before the form is closed and your controls have not disposed yet and you can you can access your controls. Its just a notification about the form is closing and you can stop closing the form. If you want to stop closing the form, you can set `e.Cancel=true`.

Comment: Does usercontrol gets disposed in ParentForm close event?

Comment: It doesn't dispose in closing event. It will dispose after the form closed.